# Do browsers correctly implement the Visual Formatting Model from the CSS spec?

Tags: css

Reading the CSS Spec https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#blockwidth I am somewhat scratching my head at section 10.3.3. which supposedly explains how block level non-replaced elements are laid out within their containing block. It reads:

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block...
>
> ..If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value. If the 'direction' property of the containing block has the value 'ltr', the specified value of 'margin-right' is ignored and the value is calculated so as to make the equality true. If the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this happens to 'margin-left' instead.

This suggests that an element will always be stretched or somehow shrunk to fit into its containing block, but that's clearly not the case; Setting a width to an explicit value will make an element either narrower or wider than it's containing block, overflowing if necessary. Also I see no sign of the margin-right or margin-left properties changing in accordance with the equation.

So have I misunderstood the spec (admittedly likely!) or are browsers not implementing it properly?

Answer (score 4):

For example, assume the containing block is `400px` wide, and the block has:

- `margin-left: 15px`
- `border-left-width: 15px`
- `padding-right: 15px`
- `width: 300px`
- `padding-right: 15px`
- `border-right-width: 15px`
- `margin-right: 15px`

Then, the sum will be `390px`, so the remaining free space is `10px`.

Since the `direction` is `ltr` by default, the used value of the right margin will be `25px` instead of `15px`. That is, the remaining free space is added to the right margin in order to keep the block aligned to the left of the containing block.

Otherwise, the left margin would be modified to keep the block aligned to the right.

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.block {
  margin: 0 15px;
  border: 15px solid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 300px;
  direction: ltr;
}
.ltr { direction: ltr; }
.rtl { direction: rtl; }
```

```html
Left-to-right container:
<div class="ltr container">
  <div class="block">
    Right margin becomes 25px instead of 15px
  </div>
</div>
Right-to-left container:
<div class="rtl container">
  <div class="block">
    Left margin becomes 25px instead of 15px
  </div>
</div>
```

In case the sum was greater than the containing block, the remaining free space would be negative. This is not problematic because margins can be negative.

Therefore, visually it's implemented correctly. However, note that under the hood, browsers might just just be distributing the remaining free space to the left or right of the block instead of modifying its margins.

This might explain why [`getComputedStyle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle) seems to return incorrect reults. According to [CSSOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/), it should return the [resolved value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#resolved-value), which in case of margins is

> If the property applies to the element or pseudo-element and the
>   [resolved value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#resolved-value) of the 'display' property is not 'none', the
>   [resolved value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#resolved-value) is the [used value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#used-value). Otherwise the [resolved
>   value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#resolved-value) is the [computed value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#computed-value).

Then, in this case it should be `25px` but seems to be `15px` on most browsers.

Comment: hmm.. but what about when the width is something like 400px which forces the element outside of its container-Does that not break the equation? And as you say, in the dev tools the margin is still being reported as 15px.

Comment: @Richardinho when its too wide, it overflows from container the direction it is set (ltr = overflows at right ). it won't shrink

Comment: @Richardinho Margins can be negative, and thus compensate the other values when they are too big.

Comment: But is that not in conflict with the spec? Overflowing the container would suggest breaking the equation?

Comment: @Richardinho Let's say the containing block is `400px` wide, and the block is `500px` wide and has no margins, borders nor paddings. Then the right margin will become `-100px`. Then `500-100 = 400`, the equation is fulfilled.

Comment: @Oriol -and of course the margin is not correctly reported in the browser. It seems that you are correct and the spec is being correctly implemented: it just _appears_ exactly as if it isn't! So I suppose my question to you is: how do you know that it's being correctly implemented?

Comment: @Richardinho Well, visually it works as specified, so I wouldn't say the "Visual Formatting model" is implemented incorrectly. But yes, `getComputedStyle` returns the incorrect measure.

Comment: @Oriol Ok. Feels to me though that the spec could be a little clearer here and state that negative margins and overflowing are permitted.

Comment: This is explained in [<margin-width>](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#value-def-margin-width): "Negative values for margin properties are allowed".